# Get clipboard data as array in javascript

Tags: javascript, clipboard

Is there a way to manipulate the clipboard data in JavaScript?

Also is there a way to implement the visual studio ***

> ***Ctrl+Shift+V***

option to paste clipboard data in cycle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy/paste clipborad content via Javascript. Check this link

http://www.geekpedia.com/tutorial126_Clipboard-cut-copy-and-paste-with-JavaScript.html

Sorry I didn't understand the second question :(

Comment: In visual studio we can cycle through the clipboard data.

Comment: In Windows Clipborad at time you can't store more than one data. In VS it may be using its own clipboard.

Comment: This technique only works in IE and can be disabled. More recent versions of IE also prompt before allowing clipboard access.