# Paste newlines into clipboard via Javascript

Tags: javascript, clipboard, lines

Before any asks, I did research this thoroughly and the answer has not been post here previously.

I want to send some plain text configuration text to the clipboard with Javascript. The text will consist of multiple commands, one command per line, so that the user may then past into a configuration file on his PC (call it "`myconfig.ini`") using a text editor (most commonly, Notepad.exe).

I tried the following:

```
var cCRLF = String.fromCharCode(10,13);

var cText  = 'This is command line 1'+cCRLF;
cText  += 'This is command line 2'+cCRLF;
cText  += 'This is command line 3'+cCRLF;
cText  += 'This is command line 4';

window.clipboardData.setData('Text', cText);
```

but when I execute and paste into notepad, 
I don't get individual lines and 
the line return character (cCRLF) is not viewable 
(that nasty little box character appears).

Does someone have a solution for this?

Answer (score 3):

The solution is to use back-tick (` `)

```
alert(`string text line 1
string text line 2`);
```

For reference:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings

Comment: Unfortunately, `window.clipboardData.setData()` is works only in IE, while IE is pretty much the only browser that does not support this back-tick notation.

Answer (score 0):

I think i did find a solution. It's a bit weird, but hey, it's for IE. It's a modified snippet I found on stackoverflow.

```
<body>
    <a href="#" onclick='test("This\nIS\nA\nTEST")'>TEST</a>
    <div id="cb" style="position: absolute; left: -2000px"></div>
</body>
<script>

function test(cText) {
    cText= cText.replace(/\n\r?/g, "<br>");

    // create an editable DIV and append the HTML content you want copied
    var editableDiv = document.getElementById("cb");
    with (editableDiv) {
        contentEditable = true;
    }     
    editableDiv.innerHTML= cText;          

    // select the editable content and copy it to the clipboard
    var r = document.body.createTextRange();
    r.moveToElementText(editableDiv);
    r.select();  
    r.execCommand("Copy");

    // deselect, so the browser doesn't leave the element visibly selected
    r.moveToElementText(document.body);
    r.select();
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using some other method than the clipboard for sending data to the user. This method only works in IE and can be disabled (and newer IE versions prompt first): [Get clipboard data as array in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767105/get-clipboard-data-as-array-in-javascript)

A CSS popup box (which the user can copy from themselves) would probably be a nicer (and cross-platform) solution. This might help: http://www.pat-burt.com/web-development/how-to-do-a-css-popup-without-opening-a-new-window/

Comment: OK, thanks to all.  I think I will go the CSS popup route.  I agree, a cleaner solution.

Comment: user478094, how about selecting an answer so your question is marked as resolved? Thx