# fetch clipboard data

Tags: javascript

i need to fetch a Prt Screen Image from the clipboard and save it in the database. 
I have never really done the save image in database thing before.

Comment: AFAIK there's no way to do it on the client side using just php/html

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get clipboard data as array in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/767105/get-clipboard-data-as-array-in-javascript)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The clipboard lives on the client operating system; unless the user pastes the image into an editor, saves it and uploads it using a form, there's no way you can get that data with HTML and the server side alone.

Answer (score 1):

You can't grab a printscreen of a client by with PHP. PHP is a server side technology and cannot access the client. You'd have to use some kind of client side tech like flash, js or java applet. You might want to retag your question if those are permissible.