# retrieve image from clipboard

Tags: javascript

HI

I want to get an image from the system clipboard (Windows/Mac) and paste it into 
can it be done in javascript?

Comment: duplicate: [fetch clipboard data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5310814/fetch-clipboard-data)

Comment: Paste it into what? There is no HTML control that accepts binary data.

Answer (score 0):

No, JavaScript would not be able to paste image data into a web page.  There are no HTML elements that can display pasted image data.

Answer (score 0):

If there's a way to grab the data URI (I can't figure out how, can you? it seems only text is available from the clipboard) then you could append `<img src="data:image/png;base64,9A8SDF7ADSF9==">` to a wysiwyg field where the gobbledygook is the [data URI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme). Then assuming you want to save that, you'd have to do some parsing on submit, write the image to a file and do with it as you will, or store as a blob or something.